# Visual Studio Data Base Project Warning: Procedure has an unresolved reference to object [sa]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Iam using sql server 2012 and visual studio 2017

Ihave created a data base project with target platform = sql server 2012
and made the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[MyProcedure]
    WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa'

        INSERT INTO [MySchema].[TableName]
        (
            Column1,
            Column2
        )
        Values
       (1,
       2)

END
```

but when i build the project i got the following warning

```
[MySchema].[MyProcedure] has an unresolved reference to object [sa]
```

i searched and found some solutions suggest adding master as data base reference 
but it doesn't work
so how to clear this warning please

Comment: This is nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: If SQL Server was installed with only Windows Authentication is there an `sa` account at all?

Comment: no sql server ofcourse has this account

Comment: of course this is visual studio warning at build and i don't think that test of logins existence happening at this level of build

Comment: i mentioned that that this procedure is sql file at data base project

Answer (score 1):

The master database reference doesn't include logins. You can avoid the warning by adding a `CREATE LOGIN sa...`. script to your project.

Be mindful that the actual `sa` login may have been renamed so deploying logins will create a different login with the name `sa` that isn't a sysadmin role member unless to add a `ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER sa;` script too.

Personally, I would avoid `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` entirely and use [certificates to elevate permissions](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) when needed. That is more secure as it avoids the need to grant `IMPERSONATE` permissions.

Comment: but iam bulding a sql data base project  on an instance that contains sa login so iI will get an error when i publish this data base becuase sa login already exists !!!! so what is the benifit of creating this login

Comment: @oulaalshiekh, SSDT will not try to recreate the login if it already exists. The whole point of database projects and SSDT is that the appropriate upgrade actions are executed during publish.

Comment: you have to add this code to sql file  If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'sa' )
 create login  sa with password='123@mis.loc'  else it will throw the error log in sa exists when we execute the publish at database you can reformat your answer please

Comment: @oulaalshiekh, I don't need to add that conditional code to my test database project. The publish ignores the login if it already exists and creates it if not. Are you publishing directly from VS, using a DAC with sqlpackage, or some other method?

Comment: iam using publish by right clicking data base project and then pressing publish and after executing it on sql server by enabling sql cmd mode i got the error The server principal 'sa' already exists ??? what about and that't if i don't put the condition of checking principle existance

Comment: Not sure why SSDT would try to create the login if it already exists. Are you generating the deploy script using a different SQL instance than the one you run the script on?

Comment: no ,when i make the publish operation iam using existing instance with windows authentication

Comment: @oulaalshiekh, what version of SQL Server Data Tools is reported under Help-->About? My VS 2017 is [15.1.61710.120] and the deployment script omits the `CREATE LOGIN` if it already exists.

Comment: my vs 2017 is 15.4.2 may be that is the difference